# Date picker with showing uploaded image in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can't use the js date piker & js for showing the uploaded image,it always cause a Conflict
and only the js for showing the uploaded image works.
there is my scripts code:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>  

<script>


if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href ;
 }
    $(function(){
        window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();

        $('#birth_date').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            viewMode: 'years',


            });                 

    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                   $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview'
    }).submit();

        });
    }); 
</script>
```

When I erase this"(the js for showing uploaded image)" part the date piker works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                   $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview'
    }).submit();

        });
    }); 
</script>
```

and there is the html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="new_citz.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="float:left">
<div id='preview'>
<img src='<?php echo $users_dir; ?>default.jpg'  class='preview'>
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="default.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $type; ?>">
<span class='desc'>upload ur image here .</span>

<ul class="ipsForm ipsForm_vertical">
<li class="ipsField">
<label class="ipsField_title">birth_date<span class="ipsForm_required">*</span></label>
<div class="ipsField_content">
<input type="text" name="birth_date" id="birth_date">
<br>
<span class='desc'></span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>



<fieldset class="submit">
<center>
<input type="submit" value="save" name="submit" class="input_submit">
</center>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what happens if you remove .submit()? .. also you should change "live" to the prefered "on".

Comment: i must remove all the scripts in the second part of the question ,then the date piker works, I am not pro in js but i have graduation project about E-government and i need help.